# Not able to dismiss the keyboard on textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

My view controller structure on story board.

Main View -> scroll view -> view -> 3 text field(On main view add one scroll view, again add one view and than add 3 text field).

On 1st textfield(Date), open date picker.

on 2nd textfield(city), **open new view controller for city list** and after selecting city it will **open new view controller for work area**.After selecting work area it will come back to **main view controller** and selected city and work area is display in second text(city) field.

on 3rd textfield (Customer), open normal keyboard.

It is working fine but the problem is if I click on **customer textfield**, it will open keyboard at same time I click on **city textfield** than it will open **city list View Controller** but keyboard is not dismiss. keyboard is also show on **city list view controller**.

**I have already try below thinks.**

I am already trying with **[self.view endEditing:YES] and resignFirstResponder**. But not getting any successful result.

I have assign the tag to textfield And also set delegate in viewDidLoad() Method.
I have also assign the delegate from storyboard.

```
self.cityOrAreaTXTFld.delegate = self;
self.selectCustTXTFld.delegate = self;

self.dateTXTFld.tag = 1;
self.cityOrAreaTXTFld.tag = 2;
self.selectCustTXTFld.tag = 3;
```

**My textFieldDidBeginEditing()Method**

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{





if(textField.tag==1){
NSLog(@"Code to open date picker");

}


else if (textField.tag==2){

    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *CityPEVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CityListViewController"];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:CityPEVC animated:YES];


   return;

}

else if(textField.tag==3)
 {
    [_dateTXTFld resignFirstResponder];
    [_cityOrAreaTXTFld resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

**I have one solution for this**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

{

if(textField.tag == 2)
{

    [_dateTXTFld resignFirstResponder];
    [_selectCustTXTFld resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
else
    return YES;


}
```

In this solution, If key board is not open than not an issue but if any keyboard is open on **main view controller** and First time click on **city textfield** it will dismiss the keyboard(not open city list VC) and second time click on **city textfield** that time it will open **city list view controller**.

**Is there any solution, if any other textfield keyboard is open on main view controller, and I click on city list textfield. Than how to dismiss that keyboard and same time open city list view controller?**

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would make sense to use it inside viewWillDisappear: in order to hide the keyboard before the controller is dismissed

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: how to close this question?

Comment: Open your stack and open right corner reputation.In that you show into below, which you asked questions. Choose any question and below question, you show four tags-share, edit, delete and flag.
Follow one by one step slowly.
Show this screenshot : http://prntscr.com/extnm5
I think it is work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this method on **TouchesBegan** function

sample code is below:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

When you touch any where in screen it will **dismiss** keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

**viewController.h**

```
@interface yourViewcontroller : UIViewController
<
UITextFieldDelegate
>
```

**viewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

yourTextField.delegate=self;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self.view endEditing:YES];//dismiss all text field
return YES;
}
```